# How do I remove language resource in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, resources

I turned localizable to TRUE and set up different languages,it works well until I test application on Windows XP.
Here's the error report:

> ERROR SUMMARY     Below is a summary of the errors, details of these
>   errors are listed later in the log.   * Activation of C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\LoL Watcher.application resulted in exception.
>   Following failure messages were detected:         + Culture is not
>   supported. Parameter name: name en-HK is an invalid culture
>   identifier.
>
> ERROR DETAILS     Following errors were detected during this operation.
>     * [2015/1/10 02:31:03] System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException
>         - Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name en-HK is an invalid culture identifier.
>         - Source: mscorlib
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.AssemblyMetaDataImport.ConstructAssemblyName(IntPtr
>   asmMetaPtr, Char[] asmNameBuf, UInt32 asmNameLength, IntPtr pubKeyPtr,
>   UInt32 pubKeyBytes, UInt32 flags)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.AssemblyMetaDataImport.ImportIdentity()
>             at System.Deployment.Application.AssemblyMetaDataImport.get_Name()
>             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromCompLibAssembly(String
>   filePath)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String
>   filePath)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(String
>   filePath)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object
>   sender, DownloadEventArgs e)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, DownloadEventArgs e)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>   next)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
>             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState
>   subState)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState
>   subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest
>   appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group,
>   IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId,
>   TempDirectory& downloadTemp)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState&
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>   state)

Please help me,thanks.

Comment: Read the last part of the error summary: *"Parameter name: name `en-HK` is an invalid culture identifier."* The culture identifier **en-HK** is not supported. Here's a list of valid culture names, codes, and ISO values: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx `Now, please VTC.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To the answer: How do I remove language resource in VB.Net?

on the explorer solotion : right clik > delete

Answer (score -1):

`en-HK` is an invalid culture identifier. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx

According there, HK is `zh-HK`